# Custom Listener

Tags: java, android, sockets, listener

I am working on a chat application. Currently i did like that when i open the ChatActvity, all sockets are registered and the chatting works... Now i want to change the coding structure.. I want to open the sockets in a class, not in Activity class and i need to add a listener to that class. How i implement this..?

```
private class Chatroom {
    private static void initialise() {
        // Initialising the sockets and registering listeners to each socket
    }
}
```

I want to notify in my activity class when the socket listeners in the Chatroom class get called..

Comment: what do you main with adding listener?? What do you need?

Comment: As starting point make use of [`Observer Design Pattern`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html)

Answer (score 2):

here is probably what you need :

```
    public class RequestSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private final static String serverIP = "192.168.1.1";
    private final static Integer serverPort = 1234;
    private ServerResponseListener listener = null;

    public void setServerResponseListener(ServerResponseListener listener){
         this.listener=listener;
    }

    public interface ServerResponseListener {
         public void onResponseReceive(String response);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
             socket = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
             // return "server is unreachable" message or something
        }

        PrintWriter requestWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader resultReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream()));
        String request = params[0] //for example
        requestWriter.println(request);
        requestWriter.flush();
        String result = null;
        while ((result = resultReader.readLine()) != null) {}
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        listener.onResponseReceive(result);
    }

}
```

here is example how to execute AsynchTask from Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         RequestSender requestSender = new RequestSender();
         requestSender.setServerResponseListener(new RequestSender.ServerResponseListener(){
             @override
             public void onResponseReceive(String response){
                 //
             }
         });
         requestSender.execute("message");
     }
}
```

read this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html